# join table with extra column and @ElementCollection

Tags: java, database, hibernate, jpa

I need create and elementcollection attribute, but i need put extra column in collection like an alternative name.

all entity is described above on  mkyong site.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "stock", catalog = "mkyongdb", uniqueConstraints = { 
    @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "STOCK_NAME"),
    @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "STOCK_CODE") })
public class Stock implements java.io.Serializable {

private Integer stockId;
private String stockCode;
private String stockName;

@ElementCollection
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@MapKeyColumn(name = "indice")
private Map<Integer,StockCategory> stockCategories = new HashMap<Integer,StockCategory>();
...
}
```

https://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-many-to-many-example-join-table-extra-column-annotation/

Comment: You don't combine `@ElementCollection` and `@OneToMany` on the same entity attribute. You can use either one of them but not both. You use `@ElementCollection` when you're mapping a collection of embeddables or basic types, but when you are mapping a relationship to a collection of entities you use `@OneToMany` or `@ManyToMany`. So which one is it - `@ElementCollection` or `@OneToMany`?

Comment: Based on the example from mkyong, `StockCategory` is already an entity that represents the join table. If you want to add an extra column on your join table, then just add a new property in `StockCategory` entity.

Comment: when you explain where is this "extra column" in the Java model then there is basis for comment. Once you get rid of the invalid annotations of course

Comment: Removing OneToMany works. thks